# Is it possible to catch a generic Python DB-API 2.0 `DatabaseError`?

Tags: python, database, exception

The "Python Database API Specification v2.0" document (PEP 249) specifies a [DatabaseError](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#databaseerror) base class for exceptions that a database driver would throw related to, well, database errors.

But as far as I can tell, the DB-API has no abstract implementation within Python. Is it really the case that each driver has its own separate set of exceptions here, simply with the same names?

Looking at the sqlite3 module source code, it appears this might indeed be the case! As far as I can tell, the C code [initializing pysqlite_DatabaseError] (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Modules/_sqlite/module.c#L378) is as follows:

```
if (!(pysqlite_DatabaseError = PyErr_NewException(MODULE_NAME ".DatabaseError", pysqlite_Error, NULL))) {
    goto error;
}
```

…seemingly inheriting from `pysqlite_Error`, which in turn inherits from `PyExc_Exception` which I assume corresponds to core Python's own `Exception`.

Am I missing something here? This seems like an unfortunate design for errors which may bubble out of an API that uses an arbitrary database driver internally.

Comment: I think you are correct.  However, what is the situation where you need this?  In general if your design has a swappable database backend, you can also swap in the appropriate error subclass.